# Проблема с выводом json массива

Tags: php, массивы, json

Всем привет. Такая проблемка, с сервера загружаю объявления, в том числе и пути к изображениям. Объясню суть, я посылаю запрос серверу, он формирует список объявлений в текущей категории и пытаюсь создать массив уже в текущем массиве `img_name[]`. Перед добавлением строк в массив я создаю запрос в БД (`если 'id_ads равен $row['id'], то добавить строку`. Строки добавляются, но и добавляются те, которые ни как не подходят под моё условие. Т.е. например я вытаскиваю пути изображений для объявления с `id=233`, в базе которого 2 фото(пути), а в объявлении с `id=234`, 1 фото(путь) то в ответе от сервера я получаю на каждое объявление не нужные мне пути к фоткам.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
"id": "234",
        "user_id": "1",
        "img_name": [
            "1_img.jpg" --- id_ads == 234
        ]

 "id": "233",
        "user_id": "1",
        "img_name": [
            "1_img.jpg", --- id_ads == 234 !!!! - откуда?
            "2_img.jpg", --- id_ads == 233
            "3_img.jpg"  --- id_ads == 233
        ]
```

В общем приложу скрины ещё, объяснил как мог. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот серверная функция

```
function adsLoading($cat) { 
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE `new_ads` = "0" AND `cat` = '.$cat.' ORDER BY `id` DESC');
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $id = $row['id'];
            $data['id'] = id;   
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $data['user_id'] = $user_id;    

            $picAds = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `upload_img_ads` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `temp` = 0 AND `id_ads` = '.$id.'');

            if(mysql_num_rows($picAds) > 0) {
                while($img = mysql_fetch_array($picAds)) {

                    $image = $img['img_name'];
                    $id_ads = $img['id_ads'];
                    $data['img_name'][] = $image;   
                }
            }       

            $vrl['data'][] = $data;
        }
    } else {
        $data['id'] = 0;
        $vrl['data'][] = "";    
    }

    exit(json_encode(array("data" => $vrl['data'])));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте видно, что в массиве с id=232, каким то чудом добавляются данные не принадлежащие данному id, не смотря на то, что в условии выборки так и обозначено.

Comment: Инициализировать нужно, молодой человек

Comment: `$data = array();` в нужном месте решит все(*нет*) Ваши проблемы.

Comment: @vp_arth а что эта инициалищация поменяет? С ней на оборот, в массив добавляются пустые строки: "", "img_name": image.jpg

Comment: Вы просто должны понять что "какое-то чудо" - это Вы. Потому что Вы переиспользуете уже заполненный массив. Лишние строки остаются там с предыдущих итераций цикла.

Comment: Инициализация массива не изменила ничего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вы просто должны понять что Вы переиспользуете уже заполненный массив.
>   Лишние строки остаются там с предыдущих итераций цикла.

```
function adsLoading($cat) { 
    $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE `new_ads` = "0" AND `cat` = '.$cat.' ORDER BY `id` DESC');
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $id = $row['id'];

            /*
             * Инициализация!
             */
            $data = array();

            $data['id'] = id;   
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $data['user_id'] = $user_id;    

            $picAds = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `upload_img_ads` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `temp` = 0 AND `id_ads` = '.$id.'');

            if(mysql_num_rows($picAds) > 0) {
                while($img = mysql_fetch_array($picAds)) {

                    $image = $img['img_name'];
                    $id_ads = $img['id_ads'];
                    $data['img_name'][] = $image;   
                }
            }       

            $vrl['data'][] = $data;
        }
    } else {
        $data['id'] = 0;
        $vrl['data'][] = "";    
    }

    exit(json_encode(array("data" => $vrl['data'])));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!) Я уже понял что переиспользую его, только вот инициализировал я его после `function adsLoading($cat) { ..` Теперь всё работает как часики :) Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: Помимо всего прочего я бы порекомендовал Вам ознакомиться с красной плашкой [вот тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php). Ну и почитать про защиту от sql-инъекций.

Comment: уважаемый. Спасибо за заботу конечно) Защита будет обязательно, сейчас пока что то только каркас и архитектура.

Comment: Тем более, если проект ещё на этапе создания, обязательно смените API доступа к базе с `mysql_` на `mysqli_` или `PDO`

Comment: на `mysqli_` и мне удобнее всего работать, в данном примере, это лишь "повторюсь ещё раз" - каркас :) Спасибо ещё раз вам.